# lxml to grab only prefix and then return the element names

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping, lxml

I need lxml to do two things:
1) List all the various prefixes used in an xml file;
2) After specifying the prefix, have lxml return to me all element names their multiple attributes.

For this lxml:

```
<pref:MiscDetails contentRef='01-01_2016' misc='wha'>1000</pref:MiscDetails>
<pref:TestingThis contentRef='03-02_2017' misc='t' qual='5'>50</pref:TestingThis>
<pref:AnotherExample contentRef='01-01_2015' misc='x'>100000</pref:AnotherExample>
<test:AFinalExample contentRef='' te='t'>test</test:AFinalExample>
```

The code should first tell me that the prefixes in this file are "pref" and "test", and then I want the code to list the element names and their attributes associated with "pref" and then "test".

Output 1:

```
"Listing prefixes:"
"pref"
"test"
```

Output 2:

```
"Listing the prefix 'pref' element names and their attributes:"
"Element MiscDetails with attributes contentRef='01-01_2016' misc='wha'"
"Element TestingThis with attributes contentRef='03-02_2017' misc='t' qual='5'"
"Element AnotherExample with attributes contentRef='01-01_2015' misc='x'"

"Listing the prefix 'test' element names and their attributes:"
"Element AFinalExample with attributes contentRef='' te='t'"
```

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nsmap` property on the document or element will list any namespace prefix:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> doc = etree.fromstring("""<doc xmlns:pref='http://example.com'>
    <pref:MiscDetails>...</pref:MiscDetails></doc>""")
>>> doc.nsmap
{'pref': 'http://example.com'}
```

Use `iter()` with `{namespace-uri}*` to return all elements in that namespace (you must use the URI here, which is the meaningful part of a namespace, not the prefix, which is just a convenience for humans):

```
>>> doc = etree.fromstring("<doc xmlns:pref='http://example.com'>
<pref:foo/><pref:bar/></doc>")
>>> [ el.tag for el in doc.iter('{http://example.com}*') ]
['{http://example.com}foo', '{http://example.com}bar']
```

More information in the lxml documentation: http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces

Comment: Thanks, I had to use getroot() as well, but now it works!

Comment: Next q: how do I find all the elements associated with each prefix?

Comment: Added an additional example.

Comment: You are a rockstar! Thank you!